# If I retry a failed fight in TWEWY, do I keep the xp earned before failing?

Tags: the-world-ends-with-you

When you lose a fight in The World Ends with You (DS version), you get an option to retry the fight or return to the main menu. If I level up during a fight then hit retry, do I keep the experience points I earned during the fight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After observing the XP needed to level up that appears in the pause menu and in the top left after defeating an enemy, I found the following:

#### Experience is kept after:

- Winning a fight
- Pausing mid-fight and escaping

#### Experience is not kept after:

- Failing a fight and retrying
- Failing a fight and retrying on easy
- Failing a fight and escaping